# JS file from Typescript file while npm install

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting a .js file when I call **npm install** with my package and typescript configuration json file. How is it generating the .js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the current package/project with:

```
npm build
```

The command you're mentioning is for installing all the dependencies of your package, declared in the `package.json`

Comment: i need how its generating js files from ts files.

Comment: What do you "need"? Do you need to **know** how it works or do you need the **software** for transpiling?

Comment: If configured correctly in your `package.json` npm will use the installed TypeScript package to transpile your TypeScript file into JavaScript code. You can read more on configuration here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html